# Make a Collection from Collection of Collection

Tags: c#, linq, loops

I have a `List<List>`. I want to get a single List from that.

```
List<int> from List<List<SomeClass>()
```

For loop is an obvious solution but i want something more better and eligent from performance point of view.

```
List<List<Employee>> ValueLists;

List<int> Current= ValueLists.SelectMany(u=>u.Select(v=>v.EmployeeID));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var list = listOfLists.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

---

I'm not sure exactly what extra info you're after. The edit you made to the question is almost complete code.

You should have written:

```
List<int> Current =
    ValueLists
        .SelectMany(u => u.Select(v => v.EmployeeID))
        .ToList();
```

This could be written as this instead:

```
var query =
    from u in ValueLists
    from v in u
    select v.EmployeeID;

List<int> Current = query.ToList();
```

Maybe that gives more clarity.

Comment: Performance wise just about as fast as a forloop. But syntactically a lot more pleasing to the eyes.

Comment: @Enigmativity Still don't get the answer, Please see the editted question for more details and actual scanraio.

Answer (score 0):

> Still don't get the answer, Please see the editted question for more
>   details and actual scenario:

```
List<List<Employee>> ValueLists;
List<int> Current= ValueLists.SelectMany(u=>u.Select(v=>v.EmployeeID));
```

Your approach doesn't work because an `IEnumerable<int>` is not a `List<int>`. Therefor you need the `ToList()`  at the end.

This should work:

```
List<int> Current = ValueLists.SelectMany(u => u.Select(e => e.EmployeeID)).ToList();
```

- [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 9 - SelectMany](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/27/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-9-selectmany.aspx)
- [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var list = listOfLists.SelectMany(x => x.EmployeeID).ToList();
```